# List Element "value" attribute

Tags: html, css

I have a custom styled drop-down selection box created with CSS/Javascript, which is meant to imitate a `<select>` element.  The box is a `<div>` with an internal list composed of `<li>` elements, which mirror the `<option>` elements of a standard select box.

Now, a standard select `<option>` element has two important components: the internal text node, which is what is actually displayed onscreen in the drop-down, and a `value` attribute which is the string that indicates the value of the selection (for use with form submissions or Javascript).

With my custom box, the text node inside the `<li>` element mirrors the internal text node in an `<option>` element.  But how should I mirror the "value" attribute?  According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_li.asp) (not the best resource, I know), the LI element has a "value" attribute which can be used, but it is deprecated in favor of CSS styling.  But what CSS attribute can be used to indicate the "value" of the List Element?  Or is there some better way to associate a value with an LI element?

Comment: The `value` attribute is used to indicate the numbering of the item for ordered lists. So with CSS you would use generated content instead of including the number in the markup. It is unrelated to the `value` you'll find on form elements. You can always depend on the actual specs if you need a good reference: http://developers.whatwg.org/grouping-content.html#the-li-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any attribute starting with "data-" is valid html nowadays. So you could do something like:

```
<ul>
    <li data-value="1">Option #1</li>
    <li data-value="754">Option #2</li>
</ul>
```

That way you could easily access your value for each option at a later stage.

Answer (score 0):

You should use HTML5 [`data-*`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) attributes any time you need to store arbitrary data on an element:

```
<li data-value="something">Some text</li>
```

---

Side note:

> The box is a `<div>` with an internal list composed of `<li>` elements

I hope you have a `ul` (or `ol`, or `menu`) element as a parent of those `li` elements!

Answer (score 0):

"But what CSS attribute can be use" No CSS-attribute, as there are only HTML-attributes.

To store any data on any element you may use the `data-*`-attributes, for example `<li data-value="some value">`.

Answer (score 0):

According to HTML5 standart you should use **data-*** attributes

```
<li data-value="value">Text here</li>
```