# Value attribute type automatic type conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have encountered some weird behaviour on Microsoft edge (14) and IE (11).
I've created dynamical elements using JQuery:

```
var option1 = $('<li class="btn my-dropdown-item">Option 1</li>');
option1.attr('value', '00:05:00');
option1.attr('value-test', '00:05:00');
var theValue1 = option1.attr('value');
var testValue1 = option1.attr('value-test');

var option2 = $('<li class="btn my-dropdown-item">Option 2</li>');
option2.attr('value', '01:00:00');
option2.attr('value-test', '01:00:00');
var theValue2 = option2.attr('value');
var testValue2 = option2.attr('value-test');
```

Now the expected results (as they appear in chrome for example) are:

```
theValue1 === "00:05:00"
testValue1 === "00:05:00"
theValue2 === "01:00:00"
testValue2 === "01:00:00"
```

Results in Edge (14):

```
theValue1 === 0
testValue1 === "00:05:00"
theValue2 ===  1
testValue2 === "01:00:00"
```

Results in IE (11):

```
theValue1 === "00:05:00"
testValue1 === "00:05:00"
theValue2 ===  1
testValue2 === "01:00:00"
```

I'm guessing its some kind of type conversion, but I don't really understand what is happening here and why?
        Are those bugs in IE/EDGE? Am I missing something?

Comment: Is it hapening only on `li` or many tagNames?

Comment: I found [something interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121059/list-element-value-attribute) about it... Look at the specs linked in comments.

Answer (score 1):

The only time a list item can have a value, is when it's inside an ordered list, and then the value can only be a number *(integer)*.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li

> This integer attribute indicates the current ordinal value of the list
>   item as defined by the  element. The only allowed value for this
>   attribute is a number

```
<ol>
   <li value="0">first</li>
   <li value="1">second</li>   
<ol>
```

Otherwise only form inputs have a value. Your list items are not inserted anywhere and are not part of an ordered list, yet it seems IE and Edge is treating the value of a list item as a number, which is the only valid value a list item can have.

`value-test` is not a valid attribute name either.

How browsers handle invalid markup depends, and it's not really a bug when they fail to do the same as other browsers with the invalid markup.

The solution is quite simple, use valid `data-*` attributes instead, and it works in all browsers

```js
var option1 = $('<li class="btn my-dropdown-item">Option 1</li>');
option1.attr('data-value1', '00:05:00');
option1.attr('data-value2', '00:05:00');
var theValue1 = option1.data('value1');
var testValue1 = option1.data('value2');

var option2 = $('<li class="btn my-dropdown-item">Option 2</li>');
option2.attr('data-value1', '01:00:00');
option2.attr('data-value2', '01:00:00');
var theValue2 = option2.data('value1');
var testValue2 = option2.data('value2');

console.log(theValue1);
console.log(theValue2);
console.log(testValue1);
console.log(testValue2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: A li does have a value attribute when it's a child of an ol. To be fair, the li in this question is an orphan, and even if it was a child of an ol, the value attribute is being misused, and the solution to use a data attribute applies.

Comment: @BoltClock - That's right, forgot about OL, and to be fair, that value can **only** be a number, which is probably why IE and Edge treats it as such